# How to build a slider which takes the url of the images from the JSON data in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, encode

I am trying to implement a slider. This slider is taking the URL of the images from the database. I added a column named as extended_images and in this column I am planning to keep all the images URLs. Because there is going to be more than 1 images I am planing to use JSON data. I have a JSON data like

[{"image":"images/places/rest1/1.jpg"},{"image":"images/places/rest1/2.jpg"},{"image":"images/places/rest1/3.jpg"},{"image":"images/places/rest1/4.jpg"}]

My Code which is getting the data from the db and decode it and return the data to the view

```
public function showplacedetails($id)
    {
       $extendedimages=DB::table('places')->select('extended_images')- 
>where('id',$id)->get();

$extendedimagesnew['extendedimagesnew']=json_decode($extendedimages,true);
        return view('single-extended')->with($extendedimagesnew);

    }
```

and my code which I used in view

```
@foreach($extendedimagesnew as $v)
    <div class="swiper-slide" >{{$v['extended_images']}}</div>
@endforeach
```

But the out put is

[{"image":"images/places/rest1/1.jpg"},{"image":"images/places/rest1/2.jpg"},{"image":"images/places/rest1/3.jpg"},{"image":"images/places/rest1/4.jpg"}]

I am expecting it to be the URLs without parentheses such as images/kollejler/bahcesehir/1.jpg  images/kollejler/bahcesehir/2.jpg and so on.

What is wrong?  How I can solve this problem.

Regards

Comment: Try looping the array itself and point the right key:

@foreach($extendedimagesnew['extended_images'] as $v)
    <div class="swiper-slide" >{{$v['image']}}</div>
@endforeach

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your suggestion but now I am getting this error "Undefined index: extended_images"

Comment: Then you're looping the correct key, so try this:
@foreach($extendedimagesnew as $v) <div class="swiper-slide" >{{$v['image']}}</div> @endforeach

Comment: this time the error is :  "Undefined index: image"

Answer (score 0):

```
public function showplacedetails($id)
{
$extendedimages=DB::table('places')->select('extended_images')->where('id',$id)->get();
$extendedimagesnew=json_decode($extendedimages,true);

return view('single-extended')->with($extendedimagesnew);
}
```

and blade should be like this

```
@foreach($extendedimagesnew as $v)
  <div class="swiper-slide" >{{$v['image']}}</div>
@endforeach
```